# Install PEAR extension HTTP_Request2 with composer

Tags: php, pear, composer-php

I have a `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/Project",
    "description": "description_text",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "http://pear.php.net"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "jakeasmith/http_build_url": "dev-master",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "dev-master",
        "pear-pear/Text_Diff": "*",
        "pear-pear/Net_IDNA2": "*",
        "pear-pear/HTTP_Request2": "2.2.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "< 4.0.0"
    }
}
```

And when I'm trying to execute command `php composer.phar install` I got this:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Initializing PEAR repository http://pear.php.net
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for pear-pear/http_request2 2.2.1 -> satisfiable by pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2[2.2.1].
    - pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2 2.2.1 required pear-pear.php.net/net_url2 >=2.0.0.0 -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Why I'm getting an error? should I really store all pear dependencies in my composer.json file for the `HTTP_Request2` extension?

P.S. If I run `php composer.phar install` with

```
"pear-pear/Archive_Tar": "*",
"pear-pear/Console_Getopt": "*",
"pear-pear/Structures_Graph": "*",
"pear-pear/XML_Util": "*",
"pear-pear/PEAR": "*",
"pear-pear/Net_URL2": "*"
```

and after this add a string: `"pear-pear/HTTP_Request2": "2.2.1"` and run `php composer.phar update` - everything is work like a magic! But I don't think that this is the right way.

Answer (score 11):

Fixed by renaming:

```
"pear-pear/HTTP_Request2": "2.2.1"
```

to

```
"pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2": "2.2.1"
```