# Composer cant fetch PEAR package from repository

Tags: composer-php, pear

I am trying to use composer to fetch pear/HTTP_Request2 and where it used to work a few weeks ago, it didn't work since I tried deploying this application again just now.

Same issue as described here, yet I can't solve the problems on my end.

[Install PEAR extension HTTP_Request2 with composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310051/install-pear-extension-http-request2-with-composer)

Composer.json contents:

```
   {
    "name": "FacilityApps SAAS",
    "description": "Facility Apps SAAS",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "homepage": "http://www.facilityapps.nl/",
    "require": {
           "pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2": "*"
       },
       "repositories": [
           {
               "type": "pear",
               "url": "http://pear.php.net"
           }
       ]    
   }
```

Response when deploying my app:

```
remote:        Loading composer repositories with package information
remote:        Initializing PEAR repository http://pear.php.net
remote:        Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
remote:        Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
packages.
remote:
remote:          Problem 1
remote:            - pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2 0.1.0 required pear-pear.ph
p.net/net_url2 >=0.2.0.0 -> no matching package found.
remote:            - pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2 0.2.0 required pear-pear.ph
p.net/net_url2 >=0.2.0.0 -> no matching package found.
remote:            - pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2 0.3.0 required pear-pear.ph
p.net/net_url2 >=0.2.0.0 -> no matching package found.
remote:            - pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2 0.4.0 required pear-pear.ph
p.net/net_url2 >=0.2.0.0 -> no matching package found.
remote:            - pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2 0.4.1 required pear-pear.ph
p.net/net_url2 >=0.2.0.0 -> no matching package found.
remote:            - pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2 0.5.0 required pear-pear.ph
p.net/net_url2 >=0.2.0.0 -> no matching package found.
remote:            - pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2 0.5.1 required pear-pear.ph
p.net/net_url2 >=0.2.0.0 -> no matching package found.
remote:            - pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2 0.5.2 required pear-pear.ph
p.net/net_url2 >=0.2.0.0 -> no matching package found.
remote:            - pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2 0.6.0 required pear-pear.ph
p.net/net_url2 >=0.3.0.0 -> no matching package found.
remote:            - pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2 2.0.0 required pear-pear.ph
p.net/net_url2 >=2.0.0.0 -> no matching package found.
remote:            - pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2 2.1.0 required pear-pear.ph
p.net/net_url2 >=2.0.0.0 -> no matching package found.
remote:            - pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2 2.1.1 required pear-pear.ph
p.net/net_url2 >=2.0.0.0 -> no matching package found.
remote:            - pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2 2.2.0 required pear-pear.ph
p.net/net_url2 >=2.0.0.0 -> no matching package found.
remote:            - pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2 2.2.1 required pear-pear.ph
p.net/net_url2 >=2.0.0.0 -> no matching package found.
remote:            - Installation request for pear-pear/http_request2 * -> satis
fiable by pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2[2.2.1, 2.2.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.0, 0.6
.0, 0.5.2, 0.5.1, 0.5.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.0, 0.3.0, 0.2.0, 0.1.0].
remote:
remote:        Potential causes:
remote:         - A typo in the package name
remote:         - The package is not available in a stable-enough version accord
ing to your minimum-stability setting
remote:           see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlr
c/discussion> for more details.
remote:
remote:        Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for
 further common problems.
remote:  !     cloudControl push rejected, failed to compile php app
remote:  !
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/dev
To ssh://fapps@cloudcontrolled.com/repository.git
 ! [remote rejected] dev -> dev (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://fapps@cloudcontrolled.com/repository.g
it'
Command '['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe', 'push', u'ssh://fapps@cl
oudcontrolled.com/repository.git', 'dev']' returned non-zero exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cctrlapp", line 481, in <module>
  File "cctrlapp", line 93, in main
  File "cctrlapp", line 475, in parse_cmdline
  File "cctrl\common.pyo", line 99, in run
  File "cctrl\app.pyo", line 1075, in push
NameError: global name 'exit' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added

```
"require-dev": {
       "pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2": "*"
},
```

And somehow this solved my problem..