# Composer: requested PEAR package cannot be found

Tags: php, composer-php, pear

Trying to install the PEAR package HTTP_Download2 (which [does exist](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Download2)) but I'm getting the error "The requested package pear-pear.php.net/http_download2 could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name."

composer.json:

`{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "http://pear.php.net",
            "vendor-alias": "pear"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*",
        "pear/HTTP_Download2": "*"
    }
}`

This is what I've settled on but I've tried multiple ways I've found on here and continually get the same error. Not sure how apparently some PEAR packages work but this one doesn't?

A few things I've tried:

- [Renaming 'pear-pear' to 'pear-pear.php.net'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310051/install-pear-extension-http-request2-with-composer)
- [Moving to 'require-dev'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452011/composer-cant-fetch-pear-package-from-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, just realized HTTP_Download2 is just a placeholder, while the code is only up at Github (which I was using before, but some of the dependencies it has don't have composer files and I figured it'd be faster just to use PEAR over forking those projects). Reverting back to HTTP_Download fixed the issue. Death to PEAR? :P

Answer (score 0):

Came across this problem myself with PEAR's Config_Lite and ended up using

```
"require": {
    "pear/config_lite": "dev-master"
}
```